# Integral of $e^{x^{-1}+x^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, power-series

The integral appears to be non-elementary. I have tried integration by parts using the exponential integral and the error function, but came up empty. Just wondering if anyone has any ideas on how to attack this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this supposed to be $e^{x^{-1}+x^2}$?

Comment: yes sorry I am new here and struggling with the notation

Comment: Most probably it has no nice closed-form solution: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+e%5E%28x%5E%28-1%29%2Bx%5E2%29

Comment: Agreed, I was wondering possibly about a Taylor Series integral though. $(x^{-1}+x^{2})^{n}$ becomes rather nasty, but I am sure someone out there has a clever idea.

Comment: Welcome. Not to criticize you.... as a mathematician Im sure you can appreciate the need for precision in ones language.  But I think you mean "Sorry, Im new here therefore Im unfamiliar with LaTeX code and so dont know how to format my math code properly"  What you said makes no sense, as mathematical notation does not change with what website you happen to be on. Anyone who is a mathematician can see whether or not their rendered expression makes sense or is ambiguous... Learn you LaTeX as there is never a need/excuse for confusion.  In your later career you will need it anyway.

Comment: Okay, my bad CogitoErgoCogitoSum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not a whole lot about this that's elementary. I guess you can say
\begin{align*}
e^{x^{-1}+x^2}&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(x^{-1}+x^2)^k}{k!} \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^k {k \choose j}x^{-j}x^{2(k-j)} \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^k {k \choose j}x^{2k-3j}
\end{align*}
so the antiderivative is 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^k {k \choose j}\frac{x^{2k-3j+1}}{2k-3j+1} + C.
$$
You can numerically simulate this sum or you can use quadrature methods to approximate the integral. The latter is probably better.

Comment: How did you define $e^{x^{-1}+x^2}$ as in the first line? I understand that you use the Taylor expansion but the derivatives of the function are not defined at $x=0$. I see that you replaced the Taylor expansion of $e^x$'s $x$ with $x^{-1}+x^2$ but is it done that way?

Comment: The power series of $e^x$ has infinite radius, so you can plug in any number and this holds. I nearly made a comment, but resisted, to point out that if you want the antiderivative, we must have $x\neq 0$. Moreover, for definite integrals, we should integrate over domains that exclude $0$.